# Geting CRM theme color using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I am working my CRM Solution including some JS Web Resource, that should add new buttons on account entity(they are placed in the form body). I also made a new CRM theme.

Is there any JavaScript function to get color from that theme, so i can use it for my button?

The goal to automatically change the button color when the color I get from theme is changed, without any need to change my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CRM REST Builder](https://crmrestbuilder.codeplex.com/) to create the following code which will return the default (i.e., in use) theme:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/themes?$filter=isdefaulttheme eq true", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                 var themeid = results.value[i]["themeid"];
            }
        }
        else {
            alert(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

You can also use WebAPI with the following URL:

http(s)://SERVER/ORG/api/data/v8.0/themes?$filter=isdefaulttheme eq true

Comment: I have implemented this code in my function (simple copy/paste), also Imported CRM REST Builder to make my own request, but i get no response. Is there anything more to do?

Comment: Did you include the header: 'Accept': 'Application/json'. If you would forget, there's not data in the response.

Answer (score 1):

The theme information is stored in an entity called "Theme" in the background. This entity holds all the hex codes for different UI elements. You can query this entity using SDK/JavaScript and get information about a particular element.

Using REST: `http://contoso.com/api/data/v8.0/themes`

And read the hex codes: `"controlborder":"#000000","controlshade":"#000000"`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. It helped me to find my way to solve this problem.

In the meantime I have founded one more way to get the colour from Theme using XRM Service Toolkit (you have to install XRMServiceToolkit to use this solution. [Here](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) are the instructions how to do it.
It works and I wanted t share it with you in case someone finds it useful.

I also want to state that I am new to CRM, so if there is a reason not to use this function, or there is a way to improve it I will be glad to receive feedback about that.

Here is the function I made. I used it to retrieve Global Link Colour, but you can get any colour you want:

```
 function getColorFromTheme()
 {
    var color ;

    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.RetrieveMultiple(
                "ThemeSet",
                "",
                function (results) {
                    if (results.length >= 1)
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            if(results[i].IsDefaultTheme===true)
                            color=results[i].GlobalLinkColor;
                        }
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                },
                function onComplete() {

                },
                false
            );

    return color; 
 };
```